# When using Ruby, is there a way not to use $ for global variables, or structure the program to put the globals as some locals within a main method?

Tags: ruby

That is, possibly structuring it so that it is like an IIFE in JavaScript so that all those variables are visible only within a function scope?

When converting some Go programs into Ruby to compare their running speed, I had to convert all the Go global variables from `width` to `$width` in Ruby, so that inside any function, these global values can be used.

But if there are 15 or 20 of these variables, then it becomes very troublesome to convert.  In Ruby, is there a way to not use `$` for global variables?  I tried to define a `main` method first, and hoping it is local inside of `main`:

```
def main

  foo = 1

  def another
    p foo
  end

  another()

end

main()
```

but it won't work.  Inside of `another()`, it still won't recognize `foo` and all the `foo` have to be changed to `$foo` for it to work.

As per request, this is some sample of the Go code:

```
var palette = []color.Color{color.White, color.Black}

const (
    whiteIndex = 0            
    blackIndex = 1            
    width, height = 800, 400
    viewAngle = math.Pi / 9
)
```

it actually is quite typical for some small Go program (or C program), to have some global variables at the very top, and then the `main` and some functions down below.  Since the whole program is not very big, there usually is not so much concern for some global variables such as the color, width, height, etc.

Comment: Your example defines a method within another method. That doesn't make much sense in this context. Furthermore you should try to avoid global variable whenever possible. Therefore please explain what you try to achieve. Perhaps post the Go and the Ruby version, so that they can be compared...

Comment: Instead of global variables, instance variables (`@name`) are much more common in order to share state throughout an object.

Comment: That's how a Go program is like: main as the entry point, and a bunch of global variables as width, height, angle, etc, I can post the Go version later on

Comment: If your Go program relies heavily on global variables, I'd suggest refactor that program first, then try to convert it to ruby.

Comment: I don't understand..? What are you trying to accomplish with this program? It won't run because you have a method inside a method..?

Comment: I was trying to have a method inside a method, like a private method, like in Pascal or in JavaScript, but then I found that I could call `another()` in the global scope, so... it is strange

Answer (score 2):

It is quite naive to expect concepts of one language to be present in another. Direct translation is not possible here.

However, I think that you'll get quite the same structure if you make a class out of original go code. Check it out:

```
class Program
  # your constants
  WHITE_INDEX = 0
  BLACK_INDEX = 1
  WIDTH = 800
  PALETTE = ['white', 'black'] # or something

  # your mutable data
  attr_accessor :foo

  # constructor and initialization of mutable data 
  # (if it has default values, that is)
  def initialize
    self.foo = 1
  end

  # your other methods/functions
  def another
    p foo
  end

  # or main or whatever you want to call it
  def run
    another
  end
end

# finally, run the damn thing!
Program.new.run
```

You don't have to use global variables for emulating constants (or, for that matter, for any other purpose). Ruby has constants (they're not *really* constants at the moment, but this is what you're supposed to use).

Comment: yup, this is exactly what I am looking for. So I understand the `WIDTH` is a class constant?  It can also be `Width` and the rule is just that it has to begin with a capital letter?  I don't really have to use `foo` like this... it is similar to the use of class constants, and it is good that it starts with a lower case letter, but invoking a method to get to the value might be too heavy.  We can use class variables too, it looks like? Except those must be in the form `@@width`, and letting it be changeable actually may be bad practice.

Comment: @太極者無極而生: no, the convention for constants is all-caps. Pascal case is for class/module names. Also don't use `@@variables`.

Comment: what do you mean they are not really constant?  This doc http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_constants.html says you get a warning if you change them  but I tried in Ruby 2.0 and you actually get an error and the program stopped running

Comment: ruby 2.2.3 still just gives a warning.

Comment: that's interesting... I tried again in Ruby 2.0. In the global scope, I can change the constant and it gave a warning. But if I do it in a function, then it gave an error and stopped running

Comment: why would you do it in a function? they're constants, for god's sake :)

Comment: No I am not saying I would.  I am just trying to see what happens what changing a constant, as suggested that "they are not really a constant"

Answer (score 1):

I think a relevant answer is this: a lot of times, the globals are really just constants for the whole program.  In that case, just use `WIDTH`, `PALETTE`, etc in your Ruby program, and Ruby treats any name that begins with a capital letter as constants, and will let you use that in the global scope or local scope inside of any function.  The convention to name constants are all caps, with underscore separating the words, such as `TILTING_FACTOR`.

If you do really need to use a global variable, the recommendation is still to use a name such as `$foo`, to signal that this is a global and be very careful.  Typically, a good program, in Ruby or Go, will not use global variables or will try not to use it as much as possible.

Based on Sergio's suggestion, this will be the form, with the use of [Class constants](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_constants.html):

```
class Program

  FOO = 1
  VIEWING_ANGLE = Math::PI / 6     # so don't have to calculate again and again
  TILTING_FACTOR = Math.cos(VIEWING_ANGLE)
  COLOR_PALETTE = ['beige', 'darkgrey']

  def some_helper_function
    p "inside of helper function", FOO, VIEWING_ANGLE, TILTING_FACTOR, COLOR_PALETTE
  end

  def run
    p "inside of run", FOO, VIEWING_ANGLE, TILTING_FACTOR, COLOR_PALETTE
    some_helper_function()
  end

end

Program.new.run()
```

and actually, you can use global constants and any function can access it:

```
FOO = 1
VIEWING_ANGLE = Math::PI / 6     # so don't have to calculate again and again
TILTING_FACTOR = Math.cos(VIEWING_ANGLE)
COLOR_PALETTE = ['beige', 'darkgrey']

def some_helper_function
  p "inside of helper function", FOO, VIEWING_ANGLE, TILTING_FACTOR, COLOR_PALETTE
end

p "in global scope", FOO, VIEWING_ANGLE, TILTING_FACTOR, COLOR_PALETTE
some_helper_function()
```

And some more ways:

We actually can write it in a functional way, because a method is not a first class value, and is not something you can operate on (we can create a Method object out of it, but a method itself is not an object), as described in the book The Ruby Programming Language by David Flanagan and Matz.  A method is always tied to an object, and is intended for OOP. The book also said:

> One important difference between Method objects and Proc objects is that Method objects are not closures.  Ruby's methods are intended to be completely self-contained and they never have access to local variables outside of their own scope.

So I think that implies that lambda, which is one type of Proc objects, is a closure and therefore have access to the scope outside of its own local scope.

This is how in a functional way:

```
foo = 1

some_helper_function = -> {
  p "inside of helper function", foo
}


p "in global scope", foo
some_helper_function.()
```

and if you don't want to contaminate the global space, there really is a way similar to JavaScript's IIFE:

```
-> {

    foo = 1

    some_helper_function = -> {
      p "inside of helper function", foo
    }


    p "inside the IIFE", foo
    some_helper_function.()

}.()

# outside of the IIFE, cannot access foo here
```

Comment: As I said, usage of PascalCase is reserved for class/module names.

Comment: oh yes I was just looking at it.  changed in my code now.

Answer (score 0):

It's bad style to use global variables in Ruby, use local variables `var` or instance variables `@var` instead.

`main()` is not needed in Ruby. You can just add that code inside main after all the function definitions.